# Falha ao cadastrar valor NULL no banco de dados - PHP7

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, php-7

Boa noite a todos,

Sou iniciante e estou desenvolvendo um sistema de cadastro de CATEGORIAS e SUBCATEGORIAS em PHP7 e MYSQL;
A logica que utilizei para o cadastro de Categorias e Subcategorias é:

Toda CATEGORIA PAI é nula e toda subcategoria possui um valor que faz referencia a CATEGORIA PAI.

```
EX:
id|Nome |categoria_cod
1 |Carro|NULL --> categoria pai
2 |Fusca|1 --> Subcategoria
```

Partindo do formulario estou enviando o NOME da nova categoria, e o select com as categorias PAI.
Em seguida recebo em uma pagina de cadastro:

```
$categoria = new Categoria();
$categoria->setNome(filter_input(INPUT_POST, "nome", 
FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING));

//Aqui está a validação, se categoriapai possui ou não um valor, se nao 
possui atribui NULO
if (filter_input(INPUT_POST, "categoriapai", FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT)) {
$categoria->setCategoriapai(filter_input(INPUT_POST, "categoriapai", 
FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT));
} else {
$categoria->setCategoriapai(NULL);
}

$categoriaDAO = new categoriaDAO($conexao);

//Se cadastrou retorna msg de sucesso ou falha
if ($categoriaDAO->cadastrarCategoria($categoria)) {
?>
<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">Categoria cadastrada com 
sucesso</div>
<?php
die();
```

No arquivo DAO ( data access Layer) eu chamo o metodo de cadastro dos dados no banco MYSQL;

```
//Categoria-PAI = nulo, se possui algum valor é categoria filho
function cadastrarCategoria($categoria) {
    $query = "INSERT INTO categoria (nome, categoria_idcategoria) values 
('{$categoria->getNome()}', '{$categoria->getCategoriapai()}')";
    return mysqli_query($this->conexao, $query);
}
```

Meu problema está exatamente na query de INSERT, se eu cadastrar manualmente no phpmyadmin funciona. Se eu alterar a instrução para tambem funciona:

```
"INSERT INTO categoria (nome, categoria_idcategoria) values ('{$categoria->getNome()}', NULL)";
```

O que diz claramente que a falha está na atribuição do valor NULL para o campo '{$categoria->getCategoriapai()}', porem ao exibir o objeto com o var_dump o campo CATEGORIAPAI está setado como nulo.

```
object(Categoria)#3 (3) { ["idcategoria":"Categoria":private]=> NULL ["nome":"Categoria":private]=> string(5) "teste" ["categoriapai":"Categoria":private]=> NULL }
```

O erro do mysql é este:

```
Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`acheimeuequipo`.`categoria`, CONSTRAINT `fk_categoria_categoria1` FOREIGN KEY (`categoria_idcategoria`) REFERENCES `categoria` (`idcategoria`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
```

Como posso mudar esta query para receber e inserir ambos valores NULL ou 2?

Comment: Tire as aspas simples em `'{$categoria->getCategoriapai()}'`, deixe somente `{$categoria->getCategoriapai()}`.

Comment: Francisco retirando as aspas simples ele apresenta erro de sintaxe;

      You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 1

Já havia realizado este teste tambem, esqueci de comentar acima

Comment: Qual o tipo do campo `id`? É `INT`?

Comment: Exato idcategoria e categoria_cod ambos são tipo INT.

Comment: Entendi, o erro é porque quando um valor é nulo, ele não escreve `null`. Tente usar: `{$categoria->getCategoriapai() ?? 'null'}`

Comment: Mesmo erro, ainda apresenta erro de sintaxe:

        $query = "INSERT INTO categoria (nome, categoria_idcategoria) values ('{$categoria->getNome()}', {$categoria->getCategoriapai() ?? 'null'}')";

Tentei com e sem aspas, e já teste com if ternario tambem sem sucesso.

Comment: Você colocou uma aspas simples a mais depois do `}`.

Comment: Realizei uma pesquisa sobre esse operador e ainda sim está apresentando erro de sintaxe:

    $query = "INSERT INTO categoria (nome, categoria_idcategoria) values ('{$categoria->getNome()}', {$categoria->getCategoriapai() ?? 'null'})";

Já tentei alterar as aspas simples para dentro da instrução sem sucesso tambem.
Agradeço Francisco pelo suporte

Comment: Muito estranho, pede para imprimir a query, veja o que está formando.

Comment: Seguinte, Com a query:

        $query = "INSERT INTO categoria (nome, categoria_idcategoria) values ('{$categoria->getNome()}', '{$categoria->getCategoriapai()} ')";

Antes de realizar a query imprimi o valor do array:

    object(Categoria)#3 (3) { ["idcategoria":"Categoria":private]=> NULL ["nome":"Categoria":private]=> string(5) "teste" ["categoriapai":"Categoria":private]=> NULL } 

O que certifica que CATEGORIAPAI é nula, depois de executar a query tive a seguinte resposta:

        string(71) "INSERT INTO categoria (nome, categoria_idcategoria) values ('teste', );

Comment: Não tem sentido o que está ocorrendo, quando eu chegar em casa posso fazer alguns testes para lhe ajudar.

Comment: Pois é, sou iniciante e não entendi o que aconteceu, imagino pra quem já programa a tempos.
Agradeço muito pelo esforço @Francisco

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O que está acontecendo, é que quando você pede para imprimir um valor nulo, ele não imprime nada.

Você pode concertar isso usando o operador `??` para checar se é nulo:

```
function cadastrarCategoria($categoria) {
    $categoriaPai = $categoria->CategoriaPai ?? 'null';
    $query = "INSERT INTO categoria (nome, categoria_idcategoria) values ('{$categoria->Nome}', {$categoriaPai})";
    return mysqli_query($query);
}
```

Veja funcionando no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/I7SPbK).

Comment: Exatamente Isso @francisco, acredito que diretamente da forma que eu estava fazendo não estava conseguindo atribuir a condicional NULL ou Valor INT, desta maneira atribuindo antes e passando uma variavel funcionou normalmente.

Agradeço pelo apoio, muito obg